# Methods for accessing BlackBerry Hub settings

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

Is it possible to change the settings of a BlackBerry Hub in BB10 using code? I need to turn off the notifications using code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the BlackBerry Hub is not exposed in an API.